# Watch OS project files (separate classes which deal with different purposes)

Tags: ios, swift, class, watchkit

I have a question regarding watch OS development.
I am still a great beginner in this field. Is there anywhere where you can take a look at how the different swift files (objects) can call the members of the other? I want to take a look at the structure of these kinds of projects.

I want to write a class which is just dealing with location and then make usage of that class in the InterfaceController class.
If I have a separate location class, from which classes should it inherit from?

Firstly, I want to ask whether this is possible to have separate classes which deal with different purposes and then call them in the InterfaceController class? Can you show some examples?

And I also want to know if I have that separate class from which class it should inherit.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what did you try so far and what exactly problems did you have with that?

Comment: @Lu_: As you can see the code is very cluttered and not very clean I want to make a separate class that deals with locations only, another class to just deal with movements, and grabbing the heartrate
Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/9jDFFzaM
So, I want to ask whether this is possible to have separate classes and then call them again in the InterfaceController class 
And if I create these separate classes in order to use them properly from which classes should they inherit? I hope you can help out

Comment: But you still did not try to create a class and use objects in currently existing one? Why?

Comment: @Are there any examples to follow? To grab the structure of how watchkit swift is handling it

Comment: @Lu_ I do not have a clue yet

Comment: try to search in google, https://www.raywenderlich.com/287-watchos-4-tutorial-part-1-getting-started

Comment: @Lu_ I tried to start with the location functionality first. I made an indenpendent file and tried to make usage of it in the InterfaceController class, however, I do not get any results as an output and the watch app cannot be executed properly. Xcode just get stuck and there are no error messages. I hope you can help out.Here is the project with the independent class: https://filebin.net/s40xlqzeukfwc39w